# C# drawing houses that become 20% smaller than house on left

Tags: c#

I want to draw a street with a panel but it wont work. I want to have it with a loop but i cant get it done. The wall and roof must become 20% smaller than the house on the left.

**My code:**

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            HuisTekenen();
        }
    }
    private void HuisTekenen()
    {
        gebouw();
        dak();
    }
    private void gebouw()
    {
        Graphics paper;
        paper = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pennetje = new Pen(Color.Green);

        int b = 100;
        int aantal = 0;
        for (int i = 10; aantal <= 5; i += 120)
        {
            paper.DrawRectangle(pennetje, i, 100, b, 150);
            aantal++;
            i = i / 100 * 80;
            b = b / 100 * 80;
        }
    }
    private void dak()
    {
        Graphics paper;
        paper = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pennetje = new Pen(Color.Red);

        int b = 100;
        int aantal = 0;
        for (int i = 10; aantal <= 5; i+=120)
        {
            paper.DrawLine(pennetje, i, 10 / 100 * 80, i, b);
            paper.DrawLine(pennetje, i, 10 / 100 * 80, i + 100, b);
            aantal++;
            i = i / 100 * 80;
            b = 100 / 100 * 80;
        }
    }
```

**The result i want to get:**
[image: The result i want to get]

**Result i get:**
[image]

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: What results are you getting now?

Comment: Added a screenshot of what i have now, i already have the houses build like they must be, only the smaller thing wont work

Comment: Side comment about design: I'd expect you call method `DrawHouse` 5 times, passing it parameter like bound rectangle (calculated from loop `i`). `DrawHouse` can either draw complete house or can in turn call `DrawWalls` + `DrawRoof`, passing them part of received rectangle (e.g. upper 1/3 of rectangle for roof).

Comment: @Sinatr That will not work correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get started with the box. Youll have to finish your homework on your own.

```
    float size = 50;
    float xpos = 0;
    float ypos = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) //whatever you do, this must be what your loop looks like. anything else is going way off in the wrong direction
    {
        paper.DrawRectangle(pennetje, xpos, ypos, size, size);
        xpos += size + 20;
        size *= .8f;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the begin! I can do a lot with this, where is " size *= .8f; " for?

Comment: If you have to ask where an 0.8 comes from in a project where you're shrinking something by 20% each time, then you have other problems to solve before programming or drawing graphics.

Comment: It makes it a floating point number. It is optional in this case because .8 is clearly a floating point number, I just wrote it out of habit. Based on the code you posted, you don't understand what that means (see answer including "integer division"), but for graphics projects, you're better off using floats for coordinates.

Comment: Mostly we work with a double, but in this case a double wont work. I had heard of a float but never used it.

Comment: A double will work just fine. But uhhh you may have to cast it to a float before you can send it into the graphics functions. Anyway, stick to floats, is my advice. Dont use a double til you have a good reason to.

Answer (score 0):

First a remark: your `for`-statements are odd, usually the three parts will use the same variable. It can work this way, but doing it like this is certainly not recommended.

A different kind of issue will be this statement:

```
i = i / 100 * 80;
```

With variable `i` being an `int`, and `/` performing **integer division**, the first part `i / 100` will produce **0** because that is the int value closest to the real/float result. And of course multiplying 0 by 80 will not do anything.

I suggest you now try again :-)